# `Error using mex Supported compiler not detected`: can't install a CUDA-compatible C++ compiler for MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, cuda

I have Matlab 2022b, Windows 11. In Matlab `mex -setup cpp` yields

```
MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2022' for C++ language compilation
```

At the command prompt, `nvcc --version` yields:

```
   nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
    Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
    Built on Mon_Oct_24_19:40:05_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
    Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.76
    Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.31968024_0
```

When I try to run [this file](https://github.com/MouseLand/Kilosort/blob/main/CUDA/mexGPUall.m), I get this error:

```
 Error using mex
    Supported compiler not detected. For options, visit https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.
    
    Error in mexcuda (line 168)
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = mex(mexArguments{:});
    
    Error in mexGPUall (line 7)
        mexcuda -largeArrayDims spikedetector3.cu
```

Selecting 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' in Matlab gives the same error.

I found [this thread](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/309117-how-to-get-mexcuda-running-compiler-settings). At least one of the participants is trying to run the same application I am, Kilosort.  I tried downloading and installing Visual Studio 2019.  Having done that `mex -setup cpp` does not give me any more options for C++ compilers than I had before.

Does anyone have any idea about how I can install a compiler that will allow me to execute that file, and run Kilosort?

Answer (score 5):

MATLAB used to have a [very stringent GPU-hardware/CUDA toolkit/MATLAB version compatibility requirement](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2021b/parallel-computing/gpu-support-by-release.html) that went all the way down to the digit after the decimal point.

You may need to check that [the version of Visual Studio you install is compatible with your version of CUDA.](https://quasar.ugent.be/files/doc/cuda-msvc-compatibility.html) Simply keeping everything up-to-date will **not** be enough.

However, Mathworks have been vague on this since R2022.
I suppose you may either use an earlier version with a certain combination of release versions that have been tested to work (we followed that table and got Kilosort up and running), or attempt some variation on the newer versions.

If you were successful, please also share your toolchain configuration so that others may benefit from your experience. .

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Thus far using that chart isn't helping -- if I try to use CUDA 11.6 with Visual Studio 2022, which should in theory work according to the chart, I am getting the same error.  Maybe next I will try uninstalling VS 2022 entirely and installing VS 2019.

Comment: This is now running with CUDA 11.6.0 and Visual Studio 2019!

Comment: @Katie Awesome. My next system will thus be R2022b/CUDA11.6/VS2019.
Thank you for sharing!